# why after the data saved it not come out the message box but skip to main page

Tags: php, mysql

i still don't know why it skip the message box of "success" and "duplicate id" although the data is success insert in database...can someone please help me because i'm still new in this php and mysql

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO kontrak (ID, NAME, BIRTH, COUNTRY) VALUES (%s,(UPPER('%s')), %s, %s)",

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Id'], "int"),
                       strtoupper(GetSQLValueString($_POST['Nama'], "text")),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Birth'], "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Country'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($db_doctor, $doctor);

  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $doctor) or die(mysql_error());

  if($insertGoTo)
    {

    echo "<script>alert('succes');document.location.href = 'staff.php';</script>";

    }

    else

    {

    echo "<script>alert('duplicate id.');document.location.href = 'serch.staf.php 
';</script>";}

  $insertGoTo = "add_info.php";

  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))

 {

    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

  }

  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));

}
```

Comment: Maybe because you redirect to another page with `header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));` [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: what do u mean is i have to delete the  $insertGoTo = "add_info.php";?

Comment: i know charles...but in my company they still use mysql...so i have to follow them...although i suggest to them to switch to PDO or mysqli...

Answer (score 0):

Regarging moving from page to page you could try.
  `header("Location: ../page.php");
   exit;`

or

 `echo "<script>alert(\"message\")</script>";`

 `echo "<script>window.location.replace(\"../page.php\"); </script>";`